# Selenium (Java) - Chrome Headless - Unable to upload the file

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, headless-browser

Need an input related to uploading a file logic in the Selenium script in headless mode. 
Implemented Robot class to simulate keyboard commands, but it works only in non-headless mode.

Here is how the upload button looks:

[image]

Clicking on upload resume a pop-up window button is displayed. In headless mode after clicking "Upload Resume" button, there is no pop-up window(as per screenshot).

Page Source around the upload button:

```html
<div class="resume_upload_block">
<div id="resumeFile" class="controls-dz dropzone dz-clickable registration_groupl resume_drag_drop">
<div class="dz-default dz-message">
<div class="fa fa-upload"></div>
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload" title="Upload Resume"> 
<input type="text" name="resume" id="resume" value="" placeholder="Browse *" style=""/>
</label>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Looked into options like AutoIT and Sikuli tools. None of the options provided info on how to run in headless mode.

Comment: Have you tried `webDriver.findElement(By.id("resume")).sendKeys("your/path/to/file")` ?

Comment: Yes @MinhDao, I did try that option too. 
`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (dc9bdf7867a80d2afa276eeedfe3c6d9)] -> id: resume] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`

Comment: It seems that you're using a WebDriverWait to check if that input is visible. But you might want to check that in DevTool (F12 in FireFox or Chrome). I'm thinking that your `Upload resume` button is actually not the HTML input, and the real input is hidden from the view, that's why you got `TimeoutException`. Could you provide your link so I can take a look?

Comment: @MinhDao: [Click here](https://goodyear-stg.phenompro.com/us/en/job/GOYEUSenusc2a35a04de3049bfb270c8d4fec5111d/UI-Test-Automation-12-19-2019-16-59-59) 
Click on Apply --> New User --> you will see upload button.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, so I need more time to invest. But I have found this: [Upload file with selenium IDE to Dropzone JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769506/upload-file-with-selenium-ide-to-the-dropzone-js). Hope this will help you.

Comment: @MinhDao: tried that option. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late answer. After searching a bit, I've found that the real file input isn't under the upload button. Here is the code:

```
WebElement inputResume = webDriver.findElement(By.className("dz-hidden-input"));
inputResume.sendKeys("/full/path/to/your/file"); // For example: /home/minhdao/Downloads/resume.pdf
```

I have also create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/daoducminh/dc2830803e3bd28d968afeade27d2798). In case you want a full project that can be executed without configuration, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried to use the findby with classname you mentioned. Getting StaleElement exception.
`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: You might find that element before some events happend that make your element disappear (it's called re-rendering DOM). I have uploaded a git repo with complete code: [TestUploadFile](https://github.com/daoducminh/TestUploadFile). There is a simple guide to run this project in `README.md` file. If there is any problem, feel free to create an issue in: [Issues](https://github.com/daoducminh/TestUploadFile/issues)